# Haskell - Bind function definition parameter

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was trying to write a test function in Haskell to mess the idea of defining and returning functions on the fly to hold state. This is my attempt:

```
fib x = aux x results
  where 
    results 0 = 1
    results 1 = 1
    results _ = -1
    aux y res = ((res' y) , res')
      where
        res' = if res y /= -1 then res else newres2
          where
            (num,newres) = aux (y-1) res
            (num2,_) = aux (y-2) newres

            newres2 y = num + num2
            newres2 k = newres k
```

My problem here is, I want `y` parameter in `newres2` definition to be binded to the `y` at the `aux` definition. I want my new definition to have the exact value `y` has up there, and pattern match to its specific value at the time this is defined at runtime. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pattern match on variables, only on data constructors.

But you can just compare:

```
newres2 k 
    | k == y    = num + num2
    | otherwise = newres k
```

This will, of course, require that the type of `y` has an `Eq` instance, because that's where the `==` operator is defined, but this is already the case, because you're using the `/=` operator, defined in the same class.